# How much information do array variables share?

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, d, sharing, deep-copy

How much information is copied/shared when I assign one array variable to another array variable?

```
int[] a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
int[] b = a;
a[0] = 42;
writefln("%s %s", a[0], b[0]);   // 42 42
```

Apparently, `a` and `b` share the same payload, because 42 is printed twice.

```
a ~= 10;
writefln("%s %s", a.length, b.length);   // 11 10
```

Appending to `a` does not change `b`, so the length does not seem to part of the payload?

```
b = a;
a ~= 11;
b ~= 42;
writefln("%s %s", a[11], b[11]);   // 11 42
```

Could a conforming D implementation also print `42 42`? Could `b ~= 42` overwrite the 11 inside `a`?

When exactly are `a` and `b` detached from each other? Is D performing some COW in the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Arrays" in D don't really exist.

[Slices do.](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dcollections/wiki/ArrayArticle)

Slices are just a pointer and a length. So when you assign them to each other, the pointer and the length get copied. If you modify the target data, then it'll be visible in all instances of the slices -- but if you enlarge one slice, the other one will still be using its old length.

You normally can't "shrink" the actual length of the array in memory (although you can certainly reduce the slice's length, so it 'sees' less data), so that doesn't cause issues.

Hope that explains what's going on.

Comment: So does `~=` always have linear complexity? I was under the impression that repeating invocations of `~=` would perform better than quadratic...

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, it's linear -- it indeed appends to the original array if possible, but since the old slice only 'sees' the original part (through its own copy of the length), then it won't see that you've appended anything.

Comment: So `~=` is only efficient as long as no sharing takes place? That means `b = a` somehow modifies `a` in the background, right?

Comment: @FredOverflow: No, it's efficient -- if there is room at the end of the array ("array of T" = "actual data in memory"; "slice" = T[] = "reference to array"), then it appends in-place and increases the length of the slice. If there isn't (e.g. if *someone else* used up that room through appending to another copy of this slice), *then* it copies the data. (`b = a` does *not* modify `a` in the background at all -- it's a simple pointer assignment. The only issue is that if you append to `b`, then appending to `a` causes a reallocation -- which is still linear time because it only happens once.)

Comment: I think I'm gonna stop arguing for now and start reading the article you linked to :)

Answer (score 3):

[array variables in D are equivalent to](http://www.d-programming-language.org/abi.html)

```
struct array!T{
    size_t length;
    T* ptr;

}
```

(plus the implementations for indexing and slicing)

the appending is special in that it may keep the original slice and append to the end. This happens only when either the [capacity](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/object.html#capacity) of the array is large enough or the realloc can expand inplace

these last things are maintained in the GC